# Показ элементов раздела инфоблока при нажатии на соответствующую кнопку

Tags: битрикс

подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать ниже описанный функционал средствами битрикса

Есть некий инфоблок(ИБ), в нем 3 раздела (Раздел1, Раздел2, Раздел3), в каждом из них поколотое количество элементов.
И нужно на странице вывести три кнопки с названием разделов (Раздел1, Раздел2, Раздел3), при нажатии которых будут появляться (без перезагрузки страницы) элементы соответствующего раздела

Возможно ли это реализовать средствами битрикса? Без использования js

Comment: без перезагруз и без js невозможно нигде, для того чтобы не перезагружать нужен ajax запрос а он кидаеться на js. уточните конретнее что нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это действительно необходимо сделать без JS, можно предложить только способ с css, и радиокнопками (обычно они стилизуются). Т.е. используется css-стили для псевдоклассов, т.е. условно так:

```
div.section {display:none;}
input[type="radio"]:checked + div.section {display:block;}
```

При таком способе придется искать много хитростей, чтобы все сделать нормально. Т.к. без доп. хитростей каждый div должен идти после соответствующего input[type="radio"], а это не очень-то удобно в плане верстки.

Поэтому делайте вкладки через какой-то js, это абсолютно естественно.